# SVM what is the minimal number of data point in the training set?

Tags: svm

I am doing a SVM classification using e1071 in R. I split the data between a training set and a test set.
I previously thought that I needed at least 10 data points in the training set to run the svm (for the cross-validation of the svm tuning), but I just realized there is no technical restriction and that my code also work with smaller training sets.

I wonder whether there is some other reason (that I would have read somewhere, and could not find anymore) to get the training data set to a least 10 points per group, or if I was just mistaken. (I have a data set with a total of 11 points per group, and I am using a permutation strategy to check significance of the accuracy score on the test data set.)

Thank you all for your help.